# Recommended way to structure rspec modules?

Tags: unit-testing, rspec, rspec2, jrubyonrails

I have a rails app, plus code in `lib`.  I have the `spec` directory under `RAILS_ROOT`.

How should I put my tests in `spec`?

Currently, I am thinking of the following:

`spec/lib`

`spec/controllers`

`spec/models`

Further, I do some common setup / use common steps (e.g., generate an invalid user) in many tests. Where do you recommend I put the modules that do the common setup /steps in my rspec tests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proposed directory structure is fine.

As for your helper modules, a common idiom is for these to go in the **spec/support** directory. You can include them all automatically by placing the following code into your **spec_helper.rb** file:

```
Dir[File.expand_path('../support/**/*.rb', __FILE__)].each { |f| require f }
```

You could just place the code directly in spec_helper.rb itself, but that can get messy and they could be wiped out by regenerating the helper file.

Comment: Where is the spec_helper.rb kept w.r.t. the spec directory? Right now, I just have the shared examples and example groups in lib/, and I run rspec manually as rspec -c... spec/